# What is the correct way of catching an error?

Tags: javascript

How can i set a variable to the message of an error?
This is my code:

```
 .catch(console.error).then((err) => {
  var x = err.message;
 )};
```

And i am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

Comment: You might want to take a look at this to know how to use `.catch()` and `.then()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662289/when-is-thensuccess-fail-considered-an-antipattern-for-promises Though its not fully relevant to your question, at least you know what your error is after you see the codes.

Comment: Little advice (kind of irrelevant), use discord.js.org for documentation. discordjs.readthedocs.io is really outdated. Also, in the event you want to kill your bot, use `process.exit();` If you already knew this, great! I just know this helped me out in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error in the `catch` call:

```
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    var x = err.message;
});
```

Comment: One example would be `message.channel.send('some message').catch(e=>{
    console.log(e);
    let x = e.message;
});`